# What is a good translation for "nerd" in the modern sense?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a good translation for "nerd" as it is used in modern English, i.e. a person obsessively interested in certain topics but possibly lacking socials skills. For example *computer nerds*, *language nerds*, *history nerds* or *comic book nerds*.

The translations I can find relate mostly to the old usage of being a weakling and worse: *malfortulo* and *malgraciulo*. The closest may be *kabinetulo* as it stresses the intellectual side, but it still seems not like a good enough fit.

So, what word to use for today's nerds?

Comment: I've seen "kabinetulo," but that was a rare occurrence, so I don't think anyone uses it.

Answer (score 7):

I have seen both *giko* and *nerdo*. They are not to be found in ReVo or PIV, and it is very possible that they are spontaneous anglicisms. On the other hand, *mojosa* isn't in PIV either.

I believe people today often ignore the social disability when using *nerd*. Somebody may proudly say "I really am a Star Wars-nerd, ask me anything". In this sense, *spertulo* could work, but it is more like the English *expert*. *Fanatikulo*, which Tony proposed, carries the nuance of a crazy obsession, and is a good fit in my opinion. The English *fanatic* sounds very dark and serious, and is often used to belittle people. The Esperanto word is not as negative, and is used jokingly too.

Answer (score 3):

*Nerdo* and *giko* are widespread internationalisms, and likely to be understood by most readers. However, they obviously reproduce the ambiguity you have described: *malŝikuleto* versus *obseduleto*. If you want a more self-explanatory word, consider:

- *hobiulo, obsedato, detalulo* (hobbyist, obsessed person, detail guy)
- *profesoreto, sinerudito* (little professor, self-tutored person)

A *kabineto* is a study-room or a ministerial cabinet, so a *kabinetulo* is a denizen of such a room, or a member of a cabinet. In the first sense it generally is taken to mean a *theoretician* or a person who owes too much of their expertise to books.

Answer (score 1):

Often it is hard to translate concepts from one language to another.

I don't think *kabinetulo* is exactly what you are looking for.
http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kabine.html#kabine.0ulo

By your definition a nerd has two attributes:

- obsessively interested in certain topics
- lacking socials skills

How about *mal-social-spertulo* or *mal-social-genio*.

Although it doesn't convey the exact meaning, if it was me, I would probably just say *komputila fanatikulo* or *lingva fanatikulo* since fanatics are usually assumed to have poor social skills.